# d3js w3c selector

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The d3js doc says I can use the W3C selectors spec to select objects in the DOM. How come the simple code below does not work? Actually nothing shows up. If I replace the selector with body for instance it works. But not if I target a specific div or whatsoever markup inside body.

```
            <html>
                <head>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v2.min.js"></script>
                    <title>Bleech</title>
                </head>
            <body>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var dataset = [ 25, 7, 5, 26, 11, 8, 25, 14, 23, 19,
                            14, 11, 22, 29, 11, 13, 12, 17, 18, 10,
                            24, 18, 25, 9, 3 ];

                    d3.select("#chart").selectAll("p")
                                        .data(dataset)
                                        .enter()
                                        .append("div")
                                        .transition()
                                        .ease("linear")
                                        .attr("class", "bar")
                                        .duration(500)
                                        .style("height", function(d){
                                                return 10 * d;
                                            })
                                        .text(function(d){return d;});
                </script>

                <div id="chart"></div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: I don't know `d3`, but why are you calling these methods on the div before it's even rendered? You might want to put the call inside of `window.onload` event

Comment: ah shit you made a point !!! could u please propose as an answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know d3, but why are you calling these methods on the div before it's even rendered? You might want to put the call inside of `window.onload` event or jQuery `document.ready` (since I see you included the library), like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dataset = [ 25, 7, 5, 26, 11, 8, 25, 14, 23, 19, 14, 11, 22, 29, 11, 13, 12, 17, 18, 10, 24, 18, 25, 9, 3 ];
    d3.select("#chart").selectAll("p")
                       .data(dataset)
                       .enter()
                       .append("div")
                       .transition()
                       .ease("linear")
                       .attr("class", "bar")
                       .duration(500)
                       .style("height", function(d){
                               return 10 * d;
                           })
                       .text(function(d){return d;});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Ian wrapping the d3/js code in a $document.ready function would ensure the d3 is executed after the page is loaded but does add an overhead of requiring jQuery.

Another alternative is to simply move the <div id="chart"> line ABOVE the <script> code, which keeps it simpler.

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
...
d3.select("#chart").selectAll("p")
...
</script>
```

In all Mike Bostock's (Author of D3) examples he uses the latter (i.e he does not tend to mix d3 and jQuery).